# Bivariate Normal distribution problem.

Tags: probability-distributions

The exponent $e$ of a bivariate normal density is given as follows : $$ -\dfrac{1}{102} [ (x+2)^{2} - 2.8(x+2)(y-1) + 4 (y-1)^{2} ]$$

We need to find : E(X) , E(Y) , Var(X) , Var(y) and $\rho$ (correlation coefficient).

I tried to compare that $102$ term with $ 2 ( \sqrt{1 - \rho^{2}})^{2}$ , but that gives $ 1 - \rho^{2} = 51$ , but that's not possible..

What am I doing wrong ?

Am I correct in comparing the coefficients straightaway ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bivariate Normal density for $(X,Y)$ is given by

\begin{align}
    f(x,y) &=
      \frac{1}{2 \pi  \sigma_X \sigma_Y \sqrt{1-\rho^2}}
      \exp\left(
        -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[
          \frac{(x-\mu_X)^2}{\sigma_X^2} +
          \frac{(y-\mu_Y)^2}{\sigma_Y^2} -
          \frac{2\rho(x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y}
        \right]
      \right)\\
\end{align}

By comparison with your formula it follows that

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)\sigma_X^2} &= \frac{1}{102}\\[2ex]
\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)\sigma_Y^2} &= \frac{4}{102}\\[2ex]
\frac{2\rho}{2(1-\rho^2)\sigma_X\sigma_Y} &= \frac{2.8}{102}\\[2ex]
\mu_X &= -2\\[2ex]
\mu_Y &= 1 \\[2ex]
\end{align}

The first $3$ equations form a system for $3$ unknowns with solution

$$ \sigma_X^2 =10, \quad \sigma_Y^2 =5, \quad \text{and} \quad \rho =0.7 $$